# Export to transparent PNG doesn't export everything

Tags: fire

I've got a fire simulation in Blender 2.83 and when I export the image the colors at the edge of the fire don't come through. Any ideas? Attached, highlighted in red the left shows the Blender file, the right is the export (placed on a gray background.)[image: left is blender fire sim, right is export]

Comment: Try exporting as OpenEXR. Also, if you're using the *Filmic* color transform for render, be sure to switch back to *Standard* for preview in the compositor for example.

Comment: That worked a little but still not exactly the rendered result. Thanks for trying!